# Limit Github Repository Access to Specific Devices

Tags: git, authentication, github

Is it possible to limit repository access to specific devices only? We want employees to be able to access our repository only on office desktop computers, not on their personal laptops offsite.

If limiting access to specific devices is not possible, what are some other best practices to prevent unauthorized code distribution / sharing?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a rather open-ended question because it would probably be quite easy for someone to just go "...but, have you thought about ..." to add another loophole to whatever solution you've come up with. For instance, let's say you were able to actually limit github access to only computers on your work network. What if I were to simply push a clone to a repo in my own account? Or bring a copy on a usb stick, or send it by email, or print out a copy. Perhaps a good tip would be to vet your hiring process a little better?

Comment: And your question form of "what are **some other** ..." is a question asking for a list of, which has no end. It is going to be difficult, if not impossible, to provide a good answer to this, instead you're likely going to sit afterwards and wish you could accept more than one answer here. All of this is a good sign that your question is a bit off-topic or too broad for this sites form.

Comment: the short answer is no. The long answer is no. It is not possible unless you host your git repository on premises and they do not have access. One option would be to require a very tailored authentication provider that can only be used based on a hardware key. But that doesnt exist off the shelf.